# What is happening in the diagram of LC3?

Tags: computer-architecture

This is a diagram of the LC3 Computer
[image]

I am trying to understand what is happening in the parts I highlighted. The part I had highlighted had the instruction bit sign extended to 16 bits and then passed on to the SR2 Mux. Does anyone know what instruction is being carried out here or what the role of the mux(SR2) is here?

Answer (score 1):

Anything with a 5-bit immediate value (imm5) (ADD and AND instructions).  SR2MUX selects whether to use the register value or sign-extended immediate value.

[image: Instruction set summary]